# Why smart pointer type member variable can't be initialized at the declaring place in a class?

Tags: c++, class, initialization, smart-pointers, copy-initialization

When I want to add a member variable with smart pointer type to a class, I found that it can't be initialized at the declaring place:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  std::shared_ptr<int> intSharedPtr = new int;  // not ok
  Foo() {}
};
```

But I can do this:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  std::shared_ptr<int> intSharedPtr;  // ok
  int* intPtr = new int; // ok
  Foo() {
    intSharedPtr.reset(new int);
  }
};
```

It seems that smart pointer is quite different form the normal pointer, Why this happens?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr` can't be [copy-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) from raw pointer, the [conversion constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) is marked as `explicit`.

You can use [direct-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization):

```
class Foo {
 public:
  std::shared_ptr<int> intSharedPtr {new int};
  Foo() {}
};
```

Or initialize from an `std::shared_ptr`:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  std::shared_ptr<int> intSharedPtr = std::shared_ptr<int>(new int);
  Foo() {}
};
```

And better to use [`std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared):

```
class Foo {
 public:
  std::shared_ptr<int> intSharedPtr = std::make_shared<int>();
  Foo() {}
};
```